# ajax call fired by custom event retains data from previous calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, triggers

Good morning all, I have a problem with a tracking system developed in jquery. The main idea behind this is to have a handler binded to many elements that could be clicked, once clicked the handler take a code regard the element clicked and makes an ajax call to a php script that logs the code, and the time.

this is working fine, but suddenly I realize that often the elements on the pages hasn't any id, or name, or class (or have arbitrary ones) which are the attributes I would like to "track".
So, since most of the times these anonymous page elements has a javascript that handle their behaviour, I thought about an event trigger, to put inside those javascripts that should fire my tracking javascript.

part of my problems is that most of these pages, javascripts and so on are untouchable, so I mus integrate this tracking witout touching anything (or mostly anything).

now, some code, this is the ajax call itself:

```
function XJAX(strUrl,kpi,isAsync) {

        if (isAsync == "true") {isAsync = true;} else {isAsync = false;}
        console.log("xjax called");
        xhr = $.ajax({
            url: strUrl,
            type: 'GET',
            cache:false,
            data: { kpiName: kpi },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: "callback",
            jsonpCallback: "callbackLog",
            async:isAsync
        });

        if(isAsync == false){
            setTimeout(function(){
                try{
                    xhr.abort();
                    console.log("xhr aborted");
                }catch(e){}

            },800);
        }       
    }
```

this is a jsnop structure to take some data from :

```
kpiList = $.parseJSON('{"idkpi":{"termkk":{"kpi":"id1111termkk","asynk":"true"}, "termww":{"kpi":"id2222termww","asynk":"false"}, "secondClick":{"kpi":"id8888secondClick","asynk":"true"}, "firstClick":{"kpi":"id7777firstClick","asynk":"false"} }, "classkpi":{"birms":{"kpi":"cl3333","asynk":"false"},"gurp":{"kpi":"cl4444","asynk":"true"} },"namekpi":{"genericLink":{"kpi":"na55555","asynk":"false"},"anotherThing":{"kpi":"na66666","asynk":"true"} }}');
```

now I have writed this handler wich should track the custom event:

```
$(document).bind('trackme',function(eventFire,elementToBeTracked){
        console.log('track ' + elementToBeTracked);
        kpiN = false;
        asynk = true;
        try{
            kpiN = kpiList["idkpi"][elementToBeTracked]["kpi"];
            asynk = kpiList["idkpi"][elementToBeTracked]["asynk"];  
            if (!kpiN){
                kpiN = kpiList["namekpi"][elementToBeTracked]["kpi"];
                asynk = kpiList["namekpi"][elementToBeTracked]["asynk"];    
            }

            if (!kpiN){
                kpiN = kpiList["classkpi"][elementToBeTracked]["kpi"];
                asynk = kpiList["classkpi"][elementToBeTracked]["asynk"];   
            }

            if((typeof kpiN !== 'undefined') && (kpiN !== '')){
                XJAX(url,kpiN,asynk);   
            }   
        }catch(e){}
});
```

in this scenario:

```
<button id="first" type="button">first click</button>
<button id="start" style="display:none" type="submit">second click</button>




$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#first').click(function() {
                $(document).trigger( "trackme",  "firstClick"  );
                $('#first').hide();
                $('#start').show()
            });
            $('#start').click(function() {
                $(document).trigger( "trackme",  "secondClick"  );                
            });

        });
```

this happen:
the first click fire the call corectly, the ajax call fire the remote script and everything is logged under the name of "firstClick".

the second click, returns some parameters from the first call, returns an empty object, then log the right call, but no call is done, returning an empty object too.

```
--------first click is done-------------
track firstClick 
Object {readyState: 1, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, getResponseHeader: function, abort: function…} <---- this is a full object, all works fine
xjax called 
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "a server"
xhr aborted 
-----------end---------------

----------second click--------
xjax called
Object {readyState: 1, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, getResponseHeader: function, abort: function…} <---- empty object

track secondClick
xjax called 
Object {readyState: 1, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, getResponseHeader: function, abort: function…} <---- empty object
---------end------------------
```

on the other file, the log, i found two times the id of the first click, and never the second click.

the "abort" thingy is something i was trying to do to handle the syncronous calls and the blocking of the browsers, in this way I give a chance without blocking too much.

the strange thing is that the second call retain some data from the first one, behaviour that is not the same of when the xjax is called without the trigger function.

should it be something related to the events? i mean, maybe i have to reset the handler once it get fired by `trigger()`?

anyone has an idea for this?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell (it is quite a random story) you are looking for the id, name or class.
You put these in a variable, and if pressed you send out an AJAX call. 
And your question is: Why do you get arbitrary names and other data back.

Could it be that classes are not unique. So when you call upon a class, it could be shared and thus request another. It would explain the arbitrary names seeing you are requesting classes without knowing which one you need (as far as I can tell).

You might be better off adding a data-trackid. That way you control what the id is and you can always go back to the one you need. Even more, it is unique, which is what tracking is all about.

Comment: yes, it is a little chaotic, bt i would like to exaplin the whole scenario